# sed does not recognize -r flag on AIX

Tags: sed, aix

thanks in advance for the help.

I have the following line that does work on linux.

myfile (extract)

```
active_instance_count=
aq_tm_processes=1
archive_lag_target=0
audit_file_dest=?/rdbms/audit
audit_sys_operations=FALSE
audit_trail=NONE
background_core_dump=partial
background_dump_dest=/home1/oracle/app/oracle/admin/iopecom/bdump
...
```

```
cat myfile |sed -r 's/ {1,}//g'|sed -r 's/\t*//g' |grep -v "^#"|sed -s "/^$/d" |sed =|sed 'N;s/\n/\t/'|sed -r "s/#.*//g" | sed "s/\t/;/g"|sed "s/\t/;/g"|sed -e "s,',\o042,g"
```

The result will be:

```
1;O7_DICTIONARY_ACCESSIBILITY=TRUE
2;active_instance_count=
3;aq_tm_processes=1
4;archive_lag_target=0
5;audit_file_dest=?/rdbms/audit
6;audit_sys_operations=FALSE
7;audit_trail=NONE
8;background_core_dump=partial
9;background_dump_dest=/home1/oracle/app/oracle/admin/iopecom/bdump
```

But, I can't figure out, how to perform the same command on AIX server.

Help is very welcome.

Regards.

Antonio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a compelling reason to use `sed`, you could use alternate tools:

```
awk -v OFS=';' '{print NR,$0}' filename
```

would produce the desired output.

You could also use `perl`:

```
perl -ne 'print "$.;$_"' filename
```

---

It appears that your `sed` expression would skip lines beginning with a `#`.  As such, you could say:

```
perl -ne '$,=";"; !/^#/ && print ++$i,$_' filename
```

or something like:

```
grep -v '^#' filename | awk ...
```

Comment: Hi thanks,
Yes I used your reply like such. `cat myfile |grep -v "^#" |awk...`

Comment: @user3665737 There's no need to `grep | awk` and certainly no need to `cat | grep | awk`. You can do `awk -v OFS=';' '!/^#/{print ++i,$0}' myfile`

Answer (score 1):

reformatting your pipeline:

```
cat myfile |
        sed -r 's/ {1,}//g'   | # strip all spaces                     (1)
        sed -r 's/\t*//g'     | # strip all tabs                       (2)
        grep -v "^#"          | # delete all lines beginning `#`       (3)
        sed -s "/^$/d"        | # delete all empty lines               (4)
        sed =                 | # interleave with line numbers         (5)
        sed 'N;s/\n/\t/'      | # join line number and line with `\t`  (6)
        sed -r "s/#.*//g"     | # strip all `#` comments               (7)
        sed "s/\t/;/g"        | # replace all tabs with `;`            (8)
        sed "s/\t/;/g"        | # do it again                          (9)
        sed -e "s,',\o042,g"    # replace all ' with "                (10)
```

Boiling that down and using `cat -n` to provide the line numbers up front gets:

```
cat -n myfile                  |
    sed "$(print 's/\t/;/')
         $(print 's/[ \t]*//g')
         s/#.*//g
         /^$/d
         s/'/\"/g"
```

which behaves identically unless I'm misreading the aix docs.  The `$(...)` construction is command substitution, it runs that command and substitutes its output. `print` would be `printf` on linux.

Comment: very good explaination but why the `$( )` ? `cat -n YourFile | sed "s/     /;/;s/[         ]*//g;s/#.*//g;/^$/d;s/'/\"/g"` where long space are real tab char

Comment: @NeronLeVelu 'cause it's easier to read, demonstrates a useful technique, and it's not hard to see the result and sub it in, as you did.